# Python Form/Prompt for SQLite input

Tags: python, sqlite

In an effort to learn SQL I've been using it at work. I keep a list of every account I work on and the information I gather while working on that particular account. My database has two tables that I update. One is the customer's information and it always gets updated with each new account and the other is an institution table that gets updated sometimes but not every time. These two tables are relational.

As I said, I am new to SQL and have been using the command line to update these tables and it's getting annoying. What I thought would be an easy solution is to run a series of Python prompts that queries the user for each column and then executes the `INSERT` command at the end of the prompt. It would then ask if I wanted to create an entry for the second table (since I don't always add to this one).

These are my tables.

```
> create table stu_info (
> id Integer,
> name text,
> CEEB integer,
> degree text,
> terms integer,
> comm text
> );
> create table coll_info (
> CEEB integer,
> name text,
> Accred text,
> Hours text,
> comm text
> );
```

In Python I figure it'd be easy to just use raw_input() and add an int() around it when required. Then use a loop so that after adding each new row to the database it starts over until I'm done for the day. My problem is I cannot figure out how to execute sqlite commands through Python and I can't figure out how to access the database.

Whenever I run

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect(stu.db)
c = conn.cursor()
    enter code here
```

I get a `NameError: name 'stu' is not defined`

Any help? I imagine this is easy and my Google-fu is bad and inexperience has led even good search results to being useless...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's as simple as needing quotes.

```
conn = sqlite3.connect("stu.db")
```

The error you're getting is because there is no variable `stu` in scope. So long as "stu.db" is in the working directory then the snippet above should work.

Comment: Thanks, that did it! I can connect to it now.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please do accept/upvote the answer if you're happy with it. It will be much appreciated. And welcome to SO!

Answer (score 1):

Once I found out, thanks to Jamie, that the filename needs to be in quotes I was able to connect to the database. I then was able to work my way through the problem. Here is my solution:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('stu.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def add_coll():
    cceeb = int(raw_input("CEEB:> "))
    cname = raw_input("Name:> ")
    ccred = raw_input("Accred:> ")
    ccal = raw_input("Calendar:> ")
    ccomm = raw_input("Comments:> ")

    c.execute("INSERT INTO coll VALUES (%d, '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s')" %
                (cceeb, cname, ccred, ccal, ccomm))


var = 1 #This creates an infinite loop
while var == 1:

    input_stu = raw_input("Add Student?:> ")

    if input_stu == 'no' or input_stu == 'n':
        add_coll()

    else:
        id = int(raw_input("ID:> "))
        name = raw_input("Name:> ")
        ceeb = int(raw_input("CEEB:> "))
        deg = raw_input("Degree:> ")
        terms = int(raw_input("Terms:> "))
        comm = raw_input("Comments:> ")

        c.execute("INSERT INTO stu VALUES (%d, '%s', %d, '%s', %d, '%s')" %
                (id, name, ceeb, deg, terms, comm))

        input_coll = raw_input("Add College?:> ")

        if input_coll == 'yes' or input_coll == 'y':
            #cceeb = int(raw_input("CEEB:> "))
            #cname = raw_input("Name:> ")
            #ccred = raw_input("Accred:> ")
            #ccal = raw_input("Calendar:> ")
            #
            #c.execute("INSERT INTO coll VALUES (%d, '%s', '%s', '%s')" %
            #           (cceeb, cname, ccred, ccal))
            add_coll()

    conn.commit()
```